# How can you maximise the shell life of milk in milk bags, after having opened them?

Tags: milk

My grandmother buys milk bags as they cost less, stores each milk bag in a pitcher [as such](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://junkdrawer67.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/milk-bag.jpg&imgrefurl=https://www.reddit.com/r/toronto/comments/2ei0l6/bagged_milk_how_also_why/&h=480&w=357&tbnid=WFtJXx5T9rf44M:&docid=QHpdnWY2Q1U5hM&ei=tSiXVtmhNsTxmQGy6ajYBg&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwiZ0MWHwKjKAhXEeCYKHbI0CmsQMwgyKAEwAQ), but can drink only 1/4 of the milk bag daily. So after opening each bag, she must close and fasten the milk bag, and to do so she has tried using a rubber band and a binder clip.

`The problem:` Rubber bands and clips fail to be secure enough, since the milk always start to spoil on the 4th day. 
So what else can be used to close the bag, to increase the endurance of the milk in the refrigerator?

Comment: Is putting the whole bag into an airtight container an option?

Comment: I'd suggest checking your fridge temperature. The colder it is, the longer it'll last (though beware other things, like some fruit and veg. like it warmer). And you don't want it to freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like rumtscho I don't think there's anything you can do to reseal the bag and increase its shelf life. If anything resealing the bag just make things worse as the extra handling of the bag can only end up transferring more germs.

My mom is in a similar situation, she prefers to buy bag milk as it offers the cheapest unit price, but she doesn't consume that much of it. Instead of trying to reseal the bag, she does two things to ensure her milk lasts. The first is to buy fine filtered milk. This is milk that goes through an extra filtering step that removes almost all bacteria, and increases the shelf life in the fridge up to 10 days. The second thing she does is freeze the unopened bags. 
She never has to throw away milk this way, and from the sounds of things she doesn't go through as much milk each day as your grandmother.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing at all. It doesn't matter how you close the milk, 3-5 days in the refrigerator is the time it will last in the refrigerator.

If your grandmother wants to spend less money on milk, she will have to buy it in smaller packages. Even if they cost more per unit, she'll have to calculate the price when taking in account the waste from the bag.

Answer (score 2):

When she opens a bag, she could pour half of the milk into another container and freeze it.  Then she could move the frozen milk back to the fridge a day later so it can start thawing.  That should get an extra day or two out of a bag of milk.